# Is there a third-party iTunes store browser?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, itunes-store, third-party

I like browsing through the iTunes store's music content, but I really don't like the UI on the macOS iTunes store application (Macbook Pro). Is there a third-party app that emulates the iTunes store (API calls and whatnot)?

Edit: I was talking about my computer the whole time, not the iOS iTunes store. Whoops.

Comment: Apple doesn't allow any apps that simulate the App Store or browsing App Store contents.  You will only find web sites or jailbreak apps that will do this.  Are you open to using those?

Comment: Websites I can do, but you can't even find applications on the internet (as opposed to a third party app on the app store)?

Comment: Not unless you jailbreak.  You can't run 3rd-party apps on a non-jailbroken device.  You can google for the websites that do this kind of thing, there's a few out there.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear. I'm talking about my computer, not my phone. Whoops.

Comment: It's your points so if you want to offer a bounty, I'm fine with that.  I  just did a google search for this and found about 15 different sites that search the app store for free.  Just sayin.....  Also, you should probably edit your question to remove that you're looking for an app.

Answer (score 1):

A very basic way to browse the iTunes Music Store with less of bling-bling and **no** ads is [nashville](https://github.com/nomad/nashville/blob/master/README.md):

Open Terminal and install nashville:

```
sudo gem install nashville
```

After the gems are installed, choose an inspiring coloring scheme:

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to set background color of window 1 to {56000,450,10000,0}"
```

Now search for an artist, an album or a song.

Check `its --help` or `its [command] --help`. By entering `its preview [previewUrl]` you can also listen to some music previews with an external player like QuickTime Player.

Comment: I guess it kinda works, though I'd really appreciate some form of recommendation or especially a GUI. I think this gets the back end down though.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an up to date list of iTunes alternatives for macOS https://beebom.com/best-itunes-alternatives/

Comment: Alas, none of these allow you to browse the iTunes store, which is what I'm really after.

Answer (score -2):

Use any third party player that can import your iTunes library.

Comment: The OP wants to brows items that are not in his library